# Can we disable /Hide Skydrive from SharePoint Farm On premises

Tags: 2013, powershell

Is there a way that we can use power shell (Not custom delegate control) to hide/disable the Suitelinks from the complete SharePoint farm .We achieved that in one site collection using CSS but as we have so many site collections with different master pages ,i am looking for a solution which will disable it in the entire farm ,Can you please help me with this

Comment: Good question. I tried to do this myself, but wasn't able to find a scoped solution. Ultimately, I ended up just hiding the links themselves via CSS. As you stated, though, that would be a lot of work in your case.